# How to read a docx file and know when the page changes? APACHE POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, xwpf

I need to know how  MS WORD page the documents. is it possible to know when MS WORD goes head-to-head in a new page with java APACHE POI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No because MS Word calculates page breaks on the fly except for the ones you insert manually. Sometimes MS Word will leave artifacts in the XML to let you know where the page break was last time they were calculated, but those artifacts don't have to be there, so you can't use them as a way to get a bit of text from the third paragraph on the second page. You have to render the document (POI won't help you there) and at that time you can calculate the page breaks. Also, since you have nearly zero chance of rendering the document in exactly the same way MS Word does, You might end up rendering the document with a word or line on a different page than MS Word does.

Comment: So is there some library(java .Net) that could help me or it  is impossible to do what i want?